# Typescript signatures and category theory

Tags: typescript, algebraic-data-types, category-theory, fantasyland

I'm wondering if TypeScript right now is expressive enough to model some typical category theory type signatures.

For example, I may have a functor type defined as (I'm using Fantasy Land version of Damas–Hindley–Milner type signatures):

```hs
fantasy-land/map :: Functor f => f a ~> (a -> b) -> f b
```

Initially, I thought I could model it with a TypeScript interface:

```js
export interface Functor<A> {
  ["fantasy-land/map"]<B>(f: (source: A) => B): Functor<B>;
}
```

Which works well enough:

```js
class Identity<A> implements Functor<A> {
  constructor(private value: A) {}
  ["fantasy-land/map"]<B>(f: (source: A) => B): Functor<B> {
    return new Identity(f(this.value));
  }
}
```

But here's the problem: the return type is not `Identity<B>`, but `Functor<B>`.

Using [this type signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) sounds like the right way, but this way I can only return `Identity<A>` and not `Identity<B>`.

So, it sounds to me like TypeScript does not have the means to express this kind of typing faithfully. Am I missing something or is it so?

Comment: Short answer no. This would require Higher Kinded Types, and TS does not currently have those

Comment: It's kind of possible, take a look at: https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts